# Knockout valueAllowUnset toggle

Tags: knockout.js

I know there is probably not a huge use case for this scenario but I'm wondering if there is a way to toggle the valueAllowUnset property on a select list?  There is one instance in which I want to allow an option value to be set that is not in my dropdown so I would like to toggle it on and set the value when that instance is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. There's no reason you couldn't just store a boolean variable on your viewmodel and refer to that in your binding, like so:

```
<select data-bind="
  options: options,
  value: selected,
  valueAllowUnset: allowUnset()">
</select>
```

(You do need to unwrap the variable manually as KO won't do that for you.)

When `allowUnset` is true, you can set `selected` to something that isn't in the `options` array; when it is false, the change is rejected.

Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/jvz3m261/